# Stack Overflow for regular expression (How to make it lazier)

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

I have the regular expression:

```
#ifdef FEATURE(\n.*?)*?#endif \/\/ end of FEATURE
```

which Works just fine when I use a regexr compiler.

My script states a stack overflow since I strip too big files.

Is there any way to make it less greedy so that it will need less steps? Specially the in between lines `(\n.*?)*?` command.

The capturing target is:

> asd asd asd asd
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE**  <<<< begginning of first match
>
> **good text to capture**
>
> **#endif // end of FEATURE**  <<<< end of first match
>
> a
> asda
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE**  <<<< Begginning of second match
>
> **asd**
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE asd**
>
> **#endif // end of FEATURE**  <<< END OF SECONd MATCH
>
> a
>
> **#endif FEATURE
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE
> **#endif FEATURE

Comment: This use of regex is crazy enough for me to remember this being asked before.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I'm not near a computer to test it right now, but does replacing (\n.*?)*? with (.*?) and passing the Pattern.DOTALL flag when compiling help? As far as I can remember, NFA based regex engines tend to really dislike nested * operators.

Comment: Try this regex on your big data: `#ifdef FEATURE(?:\n[^\n]*?)*#endif // end of FEATURE`

Comment: Like Wiktor told you last time you asked this question: don't use regex, use `indexOf`.

Comment: Since the text is too large, even an [unrolled regex](https://regex101.com/r/Y83vuY/2) can hardly cope with the task.

Comment: @anubhava

as for this:  #ifdef FEATURE(?:\n[^\n]*?)*#endif // end of FEATURE

I need to consider the \r right before \n in every line, but when I include it doesn't match anything. The expression, though, gives no overflow.

Comment: I will try now. As for your answer Wiktor, your expression also gives no Overflow but doesn't strip the files :P

Comment: @anubhava this one seems to be eternal to process.

Comment: @AndyTurner how to use indexOf to match a regular expression?